# Faster method of plucking list

Tags: r, list, performance, extract, coding-efficiency

```
  mutate(bookings_gts = map(.x = data, ~pluck(.x,"bookings_gts",1))) %>%
```

This is the code I am currently using, but it takes awhile. I'm working to reach into this table to the column "data":

[image]

and extract and map the bookings_gts using the map function. I'm using pluck() already, so there may not be faster way to do it.

[image]

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `pluck`, we can use `[[` which would be faster

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
... %>%
    mutate(bookings_gts = map(.x = data, ~ .x[["bookings_gts"]][[1]]))
```